# A difficult symmetric inequality

Tags: inequality

In my studies of various geometric inequalities I reached an inequality which seems true (numerically) but I cannot prove it. Let $p$, $q$, and $r$ be real numbers from the interval $(0,1)$. Let's also define the following function $$f({p})=\frac{\sqrt{1-p}}{(2-p)^2}$$ Prove (or disprove) that: $$
\frac{f(p)+f(q)+f(r)}{\sqrt{p q r}}\leq \frac{f(p)}{p\sqrt{p}}+\frac{f(q)}{q\sqrt{q}}+\frac{f(r)}{r\sqrt{r}}
$$

I've tried Lagrange multipliers but the resulting equations do not seem tractable.

EDIT:
The original question had the condition $p+q+r=2$ which apparently is not necessary, so I dropped it. I can prove that the inequality holds for $p=q$. A possible strategy is to try to establish monotonicity in one of the parameters under certain conditions. Unfortunately I can't manage the calculations.

Comment: I've noticed that this inequality seems to be true for other functions $f(x)$. Which suggests an additional question - what conditions are needed for $f(x)$ so that the inequality holds given the initial conditions.

Comment: Hi ivan, the inequality would not be contrary?

Comment: No, it is like this.

Comment: @ivan : of course, it is no coincidence that you treated the $p=q$ case. For a fixed $r$, and when we let $p$ and $q$ vary, numerically it seems that the minimum of the difference is attained when $p=q$. This is a familiar pattern in symmetrical inequalities : optimality is reached when the variables are equal.

Comment: I would be tempted to study $$g(p,q,r)= \frac{f(p)}{p\sqrt{p}}+\frac{f(q)}{q\sqrt{q}}+\frac{f(r)}{r\sqrt{r}}-\frac{f(p)+f(q)+f(r)}{\sqrt{p q r}}\,.$$

It is clear that $g(1,1,1)=0$ (and even $g(p,1,1)\geq0$). If one could prove that $\frac{\partial}{\partial p} g(p,q,r)\leq 0$ on $(0,1]^3$, it would be sufficient (using the symmetry in $p$, $q$, $r$) to conclude on $(0,1]^3$, and then I guess the case with one or several of the other variables equal to $0$ could be handled separately.


But the partial derivative does not seem to be very nice, as a maple computation indicates.

Comment: I also confirm that by testing on gird of points it seems that the equality holds for $(p,q,r)\in[0,1]^3$.

Comment: Yes, I tried to study that. Currently I am trying to prove that $g(r - x, r + x, r) \geq g(r, r + x, r)$ which *may* be enough to prove the inequality.

Comment: Maybe you should post your question on http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/portal.php?ml=1, a forum specialiced on olympiad problems like this inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to prove this, finally. Here is a brief sketch of the proof. I will use the following simple fact:

***Lemma***. For positive numbers, if $a\geq b\geq c$ and $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\succ(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ then $ax_1+bx_2+cx_3\geq ay_1+by_2+cy_3\geq ay_i+by_j+cy_k$ where $(i,j,k)$ is an arbitrary permutation of $(1,2,3)$

Now notice that the function : $g(p)=f(p)/\sqrt{p}$ is decreasing in $(0,1)$. Assume $p\leq q\leq r$. Our inequality is equivalent to:$$\frac{g(p)}{p}+\frac{g(q)}{q}+\frac{g(r)}{r}\geq\frac{g(p)}{\sqrt{q r}}+\frac{g(q)}{\sqrt{p r}}+\frac{g(r)}{\sqrt{p q}}$$ Let's put $x_1=1/p, x_2=1/q$, $x_3=1/r$ and $y_1=(x_1+x_2)/2, y_2=(x_1+x_3)/2, y_3=(x_2+x_3)/2$. Notice that $x_1\geq x_2\geq x_3$, $y_1\geq y_2\geq y_3$ and $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\succ(y_1,y_2,y_3)$. Applying the lemma for $a=g(p), b=g(q)$ and $c=g(r)$ ($a\geq b\geq c$ because $g(x)$ is decreasing) we get:
$$
ax_1+bx_2+cx_3\geq ay_3+by_2+cy_1=a\frac{x_2+x_3}{2}+b\frac{x_1+x_3}{2}+c\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\geq a\sqrt{x_2 x_3}+b\sqrt{x_1 x_3} + c\sqrt{x_1 x_2}
$$

and this is exactly what we are trying to prove.

Answer (score 4):

This is a comment too long to fit in the usual format.
Put $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x\sqrt{x}}$. Then the inequality to be shown is

$$
\frac{f(p)+f(q)+f(r)}{\sqrt{p q r}}\leq g( p ) +g( q ) +g( r ) \tag{1}
$$

I can show this inequality in a special case, when $r=\frac{1}{10}$. Indeed, a stronger inequality holds
in this case :

$$
\frac{f(p)+f(q)+f(r)}{\sqrt{p q r}}\leq g( r ) \tag{2}
$$

To show (2), it will suffice to show the following four inequalities :

$$
\begin{array}{lc}
\frac{f(p)}{\sqrt{p q r}}\leq \frac{9}{10} & (3) \\
\frac{f(q)}{\sqrt{p q r}}\leq \frac{9}{10} & (4) \\
\frac{f(r)}{\sqrt{p q r}}\leq \frac{9}{10} & (5) \\
6 \leq g(r) & (6) \\
\end{array}
$$

Consider the term 
$$T_1=\bigg(\frac{9}{10} (2-p)^2\bigg)^2pqr - (1-p) $$ 
Using the fact that $r=\frac{1}{10}$ and $q=(19/10)-p$,   $T_1$ can be rewritten 
$$
T_1=\frac{673289}{10^8}+\frac{62373961}{10^8}(1-q)+\frac{29403}{80000}(1-q)^2+ (1-q)^3\Bigg(\frac{81}{1000}(1-p)^3 + \frac{1701}{5000}(1-p)^2 + \frac{48033}{100000}(1-p) + \frac{58887}{500000}\Bigg)
$$
So $T_1$ is nonnegative, which yields (3). Interchanging $p$ and $q$, we obtain (4). We have
$$
f ( r )=\frac{1}{(2-\frac{1}{10})^2} \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{10}}=\frac{300}{361\sqrt{10}} \tag{7}
$$
and hence 
$$
\frac{f ( r )}{\sqrt{pqr}} = \frac{300}{361\sqrt{pq}}
$$
The identity
$$
pq-(\frac{10}{9} \times \frac{300}{361})^2=\frac{556001}{11728890}+(1-p)(1-q)
$$
shows that $pq \geq (\frac{10}{9} \times \frac{300}{361})^2$, which yields (5). Finally, we deduce from (7) that
$$
g ( r )=\frac{f ( r ) }{r\sqrt{r}}=\frac{300}{361\sqrt{10}} \times 10\sqrt{10}=\frac{3000}{361}
$$
and this is indeed larger than $6$, which proves (6) and settles the $r=\frac{1}{10}$case.

Comment: Nice. I tried to generalize this without using $p+q+r=2$ (which seems not to be necessary) but couldn't do it.